# JavaScript: Object vs True (or other Primatives) Equality Comparison (Performance/Optimization)

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, equality

So from a basic understanding of JavaScript **===** is faster than **==** (in most cases)(because === does not have to perform type-casting).

Recently I saw someone setup a high-scoped set of variables for the entire function/object/class:

```
var val = {}; // some random object that never changes?
var Obj = {};
```

then (optionally repeated) later:

```
Obj[key] = val;
```

then (optionally repeated, and possibly intertwined with above) later compared:

```
if ( Obj[key] === val ) {...}
```

My question is, why (if is it) is it faster/better than skipping **val** completely and just using:

```
Obj[key] = true; // or = 1, or something?

// ... more code, then later checking:

if ( Obj[key] === true ) // or === 1 or just ( Obj[key] ) because basic existence evaluates to true
```

I assume the performance lost from using **true** or **1** is worse than comparing an object with itself, but I'd like to understand why?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about "performance" here - It Just Doesn't Matter. Use the approach that best represents the defined semantics of the task at hand. If you really do care about such sillyness, create/find a http://jsperf.com test-case. Note that setting up such a variable creates a *unique sentinel* which may help with semantic intent (especially if properties are added); it's not strictly about "performance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not for performance, the object is better because it cannot be "faked". Consider:

```
var RED = 1,
    GREEN = 2,
    BLUE = 3;
```

Now if you check some `color === RED`, it will actually not check that, it just checks if `color` equals number 1, either deliberately or coincidentally.

Now in this:

```
var RED = {},
    GREEN = {},
    BLUE = {};
```

When you do, `color === RED`, you are really checking if the color is red because the object identity cannot be anything else.